# FTP upload through a PHP page

Tags: php, upload, ftp

I have an administration page on a website, from which the admin AND THE ADMIN ONLY can manage users and upload files from local hard drive for these users to download. The admin uses this page to upload files for his customers or to store files he needs when he has no memory device available. The files size may vary from a few Kb to a lot of hundreds megabytes.

The ideal solution:

An HTML form through which the admin can choose a file and upload it, to download it back later. This can be done in PHP.

The problems:

1. I cannot set the "max_file_size" variable in php.ini because the hosting doesn't let me
2. I tried FTP upload (PHP function ftp_put()) but it requires me to upload the file with a POST anyway
3. Even though it's completely wrong, I used a input="text" instead of input="file" to write the whole file path and upload it, but I get the following error:

   ```
   Warning: ftp_put(insert_local_file_path_here)[function.ftp-put]:
   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in path_to_php_script.php on line 70
   ```

The insane thing is... on Monday this was working, and now it's not. No changes were done and the file is the same.

My only conclusion:
With my little knowledge, all I could think of is a Java applet which does the required tasks that opens on the administration page. But if someone disables javascript/has no Java installed, the thing will not work, so it's not 100% bulletproof.

Have you got any ideas how to overcome such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to upload big files you must use ftp protocol to make it. You can't upload big files if you don't have acces to php.ini. Sad but true